# How to search keyword in all imported files

Tags: winedt

I am using `WinEdt 6.0`.

I having a `tex` file reference other `tex` files using
`\input{otherFiles}`

is it possible to search keywords in all reference files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a question only related to the text editor, but not TeX/LaTeX.

I don't have WinEdt 6.0 at hand, but 7.0. You can try `Search`--`Find in Files`. There you can search keywords in all opened files, in the whole folder or in the projects.

Comment: yes, that option is available!